# Как в списке удалить весь текст выше 3-рёх подряд строк заканчивающихся на знаки препинания в конце?

Tags: javascript, текст

Есть переменная **[[LIST_WITH_FILE_CONTENT]]**  в ней много строчек.

Подскажите, как с помощью **JS** удалить в нём все строки **что выше** 3-рёх подряд идущих строк.

В конце этих 3-рёх строк должны стоять символы из списка **[[SYMBOLS]]** .

В списке **[[SYMBOLS]]** находятся знаки препинания:
`. , ! ? " ' : ” “`

**Пример [[LIST_WITH_FILE_CONTENT]]  :**

`Or to take arms against a sea of troubles?
And by opposing end them. To die—to sleep
No more; and by a sleep to say we end.
The heart-ache and the thousand natural shocks
That flesh is heir to: ’tis a consummation!
Devoutly to be wish’d. To die, to sleep;
To sleep, perchance to dream—ay, there’s the rub:
For in that sleep of death what dreams may come
Borne on the bier6 with white and bristly beard:
Then of thy beauty do I question make`

**Должно остаться так (выделил красной рамкой):**
[image]

Comment: Вы не привели свой код

Comment: const str = [[LIST_WITH_FILE_CONTENT]];
const punct = [[SYMBOLS]];
const numStrWithPunctEnd = 3;
const arr = str.split('\n');
const index = arr.findIndex(function(n, i, a) {
  return this.every(m => punct.includes(a[i + m].slice(-1)));
}, [...Array(numStrWithPunctEnd).keys()]);
const result = index !== -1 ? arr.slice(index).join('\n') : str;
[[LIST_WITH_FILE_CONTENT]]=result;

Comment: но выдаёт ошибку: https://habrastorage.org/webt/62/54/96/625496ff62a47926412147.jpeg

Comment: Спасибо, но лучше оформить код в вопросе. Да, и рад что Вы  не бот. Было бы правильно реагировать на вопросы и ответы с решениями тех, кто пытается помочь.

Answer (score 0):

```
function qwe(LIST_WITH_FILE_CONTENT) {
    let splittedList = LIST_WITH_FILE_CONTENT.split('\n').reverse();

    if (splittedList.length < 3) {
        return LIST_WITH_FILE_CONTENT;
    }

    let resultList = [];
    const SYMBOLS = `.,!?"':”“;`;

    for (let i = 0; i < splittedList.length - 2; i) {
        let currentLine = splittedList[i];
        let secondLine = splittedList[i + 1];
        let thirdLine = splittedList[i + 2];

        if (SYMBOLS.includes(currentLine[currentLine.length - 1])) {
            resultList.push(currentLine);

            if (SYMBOLS.includes(secondLine[secondLine.length - 1])) {
                resultList.push(secondLine);

                if (SYMBOLS.includes(thirdLine[thirdLine.length - 1])) {
                    resultList.push(thirdLine);
                    break;
                } else {
                    resultList.push(thirdLine);
                    i += 3;
                }
            } else {
                resultList.push(secondLine);
                i += 2;
            }
        } else {
            resultList.push(currentLine);
            i += 1;
        }
    }

    return resultList.reverse().join('\n');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Счетчик - сила!

```js
let text = `Or to take arms against a sea of troubles?
And by opposing end them. To die—to sleep
No more; and by a sleep to say we end.
The heart-ache and the thousand natural shocks
That flesh is heir to: ’tis a consummation!
Devoutly to be wish’d. To die, to sleep;
To sleep, perchance to dream—ay, there’s the rub:
For in that sleep of death what dreams may come
Borne on the bier6 with white and bristly beard:
Then of thy beauty do I question make`;

let symbols = /[.,!?"':;”“]/;

function process(text)
{
  let counter = 0;

  return text.split('\n').reverse().filter(function(v) {
    if (counter == 3) return false;
    else {
      counter = symbols.test(v.slice(-1)) ? counter + 1 : 0;
      return true;
    }
  }).reverse().join('\n');
}

console.log(process(text));
```

Answer (score 0):

@laukhin-andrey Содержание переменной [[LIST_WITH_FILE_CONTENT]] не поменялось(

```js
let symbols = [[SYMBOLS]];
let listcontent = [[LIST_WITH_FILE_CONTENT]]; 
function process(text)
{
  let counter = 0;

  return text.split('\n').reverse().filter(function(v) {
    if (counter == 3) return false;
    else {
      counter = symbols.test(v.slice(-1)) ? counter + 1 : 0;
      return true;
    }
  }).reverse().join('\n');
}
[[LIST_WITH_FILE_CONTENT]]=listcontent;
```

Comment: похоже, это не ответ, а дополнение к вопросу. если так и есть, то дополните, пожалуйста, текст вопроса, нажав ссылку «править» ниже текста вопроса, а данный «ответ», пожалуйста, удалите

Comment: А зачем вы оброрачиваете в [[]] переменные SYMBOLS и LIST_WITH_FILE_CONTENT?

Comment: Вам дали функцию process, нужно ее вызвать `LIST_WITH_FILE_CONTENT = process(LIST_WITH_FILE_CONTENT)`. Тогда в LIST_WITH_FILE_CONTENT будет нужный результат

Comment: @Citizen_39895
Сначала заливаю символы для реакции на них в переменную symbols вот так: 
let symbols = [[SYMBOLS]];

Заливаю в переменную listcontent мой текст для обработки содержащийся внутри [[LIST_WITH_FILE_CONTENT]] вот так: let listcontent = [[LIST_WITH_FILE_CONTENT]];


Далее вызываю process на что она обработала  текст в переменной listcontent вот так: function process(listcontent)

Comment: @Citizen_39895
Не пойму где ошибся. Код:
let symbols = [[SYMBOLS]];
let listcontent = [[LIST_WITH_FILE_CONTENT]];
function process(listcontent)
{
  let counter = 0;

  return text.split('\n').reverse().filter(function(v) {
    if (counter == 3) return false;
    else {
      counter = symbols.test(v.slice(-1)) ? counter + 1 : 0;
      return true;
    }
  }).reverse().join('\n');
}
[[LIST_WITH_FILE_CONTENT]]=listcontent;

Comment: @Citizen_39895 оборачиваю [[LIST_WITH_FILE_CONTENT]] в [[]] потому что в моём интерпретаторе JS (в browser automation studio ) вот так задаётся переменная внутри которой находится текст , в моем случае внутри [[LIST_WITH_FILE_CONTENT]] находится текст для ого обработки функцией process

Comment: @MikhailEliseev Я обновил свой ответ, чтобы можно было проверить работоспособность функции. Единственный момент, на который нужно обратить внимание, это параметр метода split(). В конце строки может быть просто символ `\n`, может быть последовательность `\r\n`. Другое решение: заменить `v.slice(-1)` на `v.trimRight().slice(-1)`. Если проблема не в этом, то она связана с интеграцией этой функции в Ваш код.

Comment: @MikhailEliseev Хотя посмотрите внимательно на Ваш код. Он выглядит так: `A = B; B = A`. Должно быть `A = B; B = process(A)`. Либо перенесите тело функции в основной модуль, если смущает.

Comment: @MikhailEliseev, Да, если набор символов задаете не самостоятельно в коде, то тест проверки замените на инструкцию с методом `includes()`. У меня тест по регулярному выражению. Бог свидетель, помогал как мог.